# pods are not created in namespace from pod security policy

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd, podsecuritypolicy

I know the psp is deprecated,but it is still mandatory in our cluster. We are having a problem with the deployment of linkerd viz. I created a role,rolebinding,psp
there is a problem when creating floors in namespace linkerd-viz

```
8m27s       Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/web-cb5fc858f             Error creating: pods "web-cb5fc858f-" is forbidden: PodSecurityPolicy: unable to admit pod: [spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_ADMIN": capability may not be added spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_RAW": capability may not be added spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation: Invalid value: true: Allowing privilege escalation for containers is not allowed pod.metadata.annotations[seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/linkerd-init]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation: Invalid value: true: Allowing privilege escalation for containers is not allowed pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/linkerd-proxy]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/web]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set]
11m         Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/web-cb5fc858f             Error creating: pods "web-cb5fc858f-" is forbidden: PodSecurityPolicy: unable to admit pod: [pod.metadata.annotations[seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/linkerd-init]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation: Invalid value: true: Allowing privilege escalation for containers is not allowed pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/linkerd-proxy]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/web]: Forbidden: seccomp may not be set spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_ADMIN": capability may not be added spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_RAW": capability may not be added spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation: Invalid value: true: Allowing privilege escalation for containers is not allowed]
```

psp

```
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  labels:
    linkerd.io/control-plane-ns: linkerd
  name: linkerd-linkerd-control-plane
spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  allowedCapabilities:
  - NET_ADMIN
  - NET_RAW
  fsGroup:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 1
    rule: MustRunAs
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  requiredDropCapabilities:
  - ALL
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 1
    rule: MustRunAs
  volumes:
  - configMap
  - emptyDir
  - secret
  - projected
  - downwardAPI
  - persistentVolumeClaim
```

role

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Role
  metadata:
    labels:
      linkerd.io/extension: viz
    name: psp
    namespace: linkerd-viz
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - policy
    - extensions
    resourceNames:
    - linkerd-linkerd-control-plane
    resources:
    - podsecuritypolicies
    verbs:
    - use
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

rolebinding

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    labels:
      linkerd.io/extension: viz
      namespace: linkerd-viz
    name: viz-psp
    namespace: linkerd-viz
  roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: Role
    name: psp
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tap
    namespace: linkerd-viz
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: web
    namespace: linkerd-viz
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: prometheus
    namespace: linkerd-viz
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: metrics-api
    namespace: linkerd-viz
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tap-injector
    namespace: linkerd-viz
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

what could be the reason? it seems that all policies are issued correctly

Comment: Your PSP set as RunAsUser, AllowPrivilegeEscalation PSP controls whether or not a user is allowed to set the security context of a container to **True**. Setting it to False ensures that no child process of a container can gain more privileges than its parent.

Try to set **AllowPrivilegeEscalation to False**, to ensure **RunAsUser** commands cannot bypass their existing sets of permissions.

Comment: @Veera Nagireddy Unfortunately it didn't help, I even. it runs only if I use the standard privileged psp, everything is allowed in it.there is a feeling that I need to give out rights to something else in my own policy

Comment: Refer [Debugging k8s PSP](https://medium.com/@suruti94/debugging-k8s-podsecuritypolicy-related-issues-9730c90d9eff),which may help to resolve your issue.